# Update multiple values in UseState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following object;
{ Email: "xyz.abc@gmail.com", FullName: "Xyz Abc", GivenName: "Xyz", FamilyName: "Abc" }

In a user profile view I am setting "given name" and "family name" and allow the user to change both given and family name.

```
const setFormInput = (fieldName, value) => {

        switch (fieldName) {
            case 'firstName':
                setUserDetail({...userDetail, GivenName: value });
                break;
            case 'lastName':
                setUserDetail({...userDetail, FamilyName: value});
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

}
```

And in the text field I call the above method

```
<TextField variant="outlined" sx={{ width: "100%" }} value={userDetail.GivenName ?? ''}
                            label="First Name" placeholder="Enter your first name"
                            onChange={ (e) => {setFormInput('firstName', e.target.value)}}></TextField>
```

On the on change, while user setting either the given name or the family name, I want to update the
"FullName" attribute as well.

As an example, setUserDetail({...userDetail, GivenName: value, FullName: value + " " + FamilyName });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update multiple keys of an object value stored in the state, like:

```
setUserDetail((details) => ({
  ...details,
  GivenName: value,
  FullName: `${value} ${details.FamilyName}`,
}))
```

---

Pass a callback function to `setUserDetail` (rather than passing a value, especially if you need to refer to old value within setUserDetail function).

> If you pass a function as nextState, it will be treated as an updater function. It must be pure, should take the pending state as its only argument, and should return the next state. React will put your updater function in a queue and re-render your component
>
> https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate